Why do I get a syntax error using the ternary operator with function calls?
I'm writing a code in SystemVerilog, and I'm trying to use the ternary operator to decide between two function calls. Here's my code:
module tb;
  int a = 1, b = 4;
  initial begin
    b > a ? $display("%0d", b) : $display("Value: %0d", a); // Syntax error
    $display("%0d", b > a ? b : a); // This works correctly
  end
endmodule

In the line b > a ? print(b) : print(a);, I get a syntax error, but the line print(b > a ? b : a); works perfectly. I don’t understand why using the ternary operator directly with function calls causes a syntax error.
Can someone explain why this happens and how to fix it?

The function calls are not the cause of the syntax error.  The problem is that the ?: construct is simply an operator; it is not a complete statement by itself.  You would still get a syntax error with the following code for example:
b > a ? b : a;

There are no function calls in that line.  You would get the same syntax error with any operator, such as:
a || b;

To call a function based on a condition, you should use the if/else procedural code:
module tb;
  int a = 1, b = 4;
  initial begin
    if (b > a)
        $display("%0d", b);
    else
        $display("Value: %0d", a);
  end
endmodule

